# Write a file to usr

Tags: non-root-user

I want to copy a file from the documents folder to `/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica`, but if I try I got the message `Access denied. Could not write to...`

How can I solve that problem?

Answer (score 2):

By default, a non-root user won't be able to write to `/usr/local`.  If you have root access (may via `sudo`), then you can use that to perform the copy operation.

Comment: I tried sudo su but it didn't work after that.

Comment: You appear to have tagged the question "/not-root-user."  What as the error message after you used sudo?  Please paste the exact command you used.

Comment: If you've tried using `su` or `sudo`, please edit your question (i.e., don't put it in a comment here) and show us (1) what you've tried, and (2) the response you received when you tried it.